# Embed raw bytes as a PDF in JSP

Tags: jsp, jsf, pdf, javabeans

I have a bean with the raw bytes of a PDF that is generated at the user's request. I want to display this PDF to the user without really persisting the PDF file on my server.

In my jsp I have tried tags like

```
<object data="#{bean.pdfBytes}" type="application/pdf" ></object>
<object type="application/pdf" width="600" height="400">
    <h:outputFormat value="#{bean.pdfBytes}" escape="false"/>
</object>
```

but this fails terribly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need more lines from your JSP. Is PDF object alone in JSP? Then why not use a servlet to feed data to browser and let it render itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I want to display this PDF to the user without really persisting the PDF file on my server.*

Write it to the output stream of the response. Let's assume that you're using iText to generate the PDF, pass the response's output stream to `PdfWrter#getInstance()`.

```
public void download() throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
    document.open();
    // Build document.

    context.responseComplete();
}
```

This will however display the PDF in its entirety in the browser. If you want a *Save As* dialogue, just change the `inline` part in the header to `attachment`. Or if you really want to have it embedded in an `<object>`, then you'd need to create a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) and do the above `response` job inside the `doGet()` method and finally let `<object>`'s URL point to that servlet.