# Facelet present dynamically loaded PDF from DB

Tags: jsf, servlets

Based on the selection of a few form elements, I want to dynamically load a PDF file into an embed/object tag which is stored in a database.

### Serving the PDF

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437234/embed-raw-bytes-as-a-pdf-in-jsp) solution to serve a PDF from a servlet.

- Is this the right approach when using Facelets? Because I thought when using facelets, I shouldn't need Servlets so how would I do that with a Bean?
- As I load the PDF dynamically from a Database, I don't have access to a file on the file-system so in which way would I have to modify the `response.setHeader`?

### Call from JSF

I thought that I would somehow first trigger a javascript function to update the content of the `src` attribute in the embed tag and then with the [ajax](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_ajax.html) tag from the jsf core library trigger the rerendering of the embed element.

Is this the right approach?

```
<embed src="#{pdfServlet.getPdf[desiredFileId]}"></embed>
```

Comment: facelets/core JSF doesn't solve all problems you may have (far from it), that's why extension packages such as Primefaces exist. It has a [media component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml) which can display PDFs, among other types of content commonly supported embedded in a browser.

Comment: My company removes media content from the jsf tag libraries. I solved it for now by having an instance variable in the bean which contains the base64 encoded PDF and changing the src attribute to `data:application/pdf;base64,<base64encodedPDF>`.